# PHP Thumbnail Image Resizing with proportions

Tags: php, image-processing, resize, thumbnails, autoresize

As a brief run down, I am currently making a dating type site. Users can create accounts and upload profile pictures (up to 8). In order to display these in the browse area of the website, I am looking for a way in PHP (with third party processor/scripts) to resize all images uploaded to have thumbnails that adhere to certain dimensions.

As an example, I will want "profile" images (thumbnails) to be NO larger than 120*150px. The scripting needs to resize uploaded images (regardless of whether they are portrait or landscape, and regardless of proportions) to adhere to these dimensions without getting stretched.

The width (eg. 120pixels) should always remain the same, but the height (eg. 150px) can vary in order to keep the image in proportion. If it's a landscape photo, I'm assuming the script would need to take a chunk out of the middle of the image?

The reason that all images to be resized is so that when profiles are display in a grid that all thumbnails are roughly the same size.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

```
$maxwidth = 120;
$maxheight = 150;

$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($jpgimage); 
//or imagecreatefrompng,imagecreatefromgif,etc. depending on user's uploaded file extension

$width = imagesx($img); //get width and height of original image
$height = imagesy($img);

//determine which side is the longest to use in calculating length of the shorter side, since the longest will be the max size for whichever side is longest.    
if ($height > $width) 
{   
$ratio = $maxheight / $height;  
$newheight = $maxheight;
$newwidth = $width * $ratio; 
}
else 
{
$ratio = $maxwidth / $width;   
$newwidth = $maxwidth;  
$newheight = $height * $ratio;   
}

//create new image resource to hold the resized image
$newimg = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight); 

$palsize = ImageColorsTotal($img);  //Get palette size for original image
for ($i = 0; $i < $palsize; $i++) //Assign color palette to new image
{ 
$colors = ImageColorsForIndex($img, $i);   
ImageColorAllocate($newimg, $colors['red'], $colors['green'], $colors['blue']);
} 

//copy original image into new image at new size.
imagecopyresized($newimg, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

imagejpeg($newimg,$outputfile); //$output file is the path/filename where you wish to save the file.  
//Have to figure that one out yourself using whatever rules you want.  Can use imagegif() or imagepng() or whatever.
```

This will shrink any images down proportionally based on whichever side is longer (width or height), to the maximum size.  It will also blow up any images smaller than max, which you can stop with a bit of checking on whether or not both width and height are less than their max.  So, a 200x300 image will be shrunk to 100x150, and a 300x200 image will be shrunk to 120x80.

Hmm, you want the width to always be 120, so it would change a bit, and yeah, it would have to cut something out in the case of an image like 200x300, because that would shrink to 120x180 without any distortion, or it would have to shrink it farther and letterbox it, but that should get you started nicely.

Letterboxing this example would just involve figuring out what the proper x and y to start the drawing to the new image would be in the imagecopyresized() function.  In the case of something like 100x150, the X would be 10, I think, so there would be 10px of blank space on each side for 120x150 in the end.  Letterboxing 120x80 X would be 0 but Y would be 35, so there would be 35px of blank space above and below for 120x150.

You'd also want to make $newimg with $maxwidth,$maxheight rather than $newwidth,$newheight, but the imagecopyresized() would still use both $new values.

Since I'm bored and don't have anything else to do, these changes would do it:

```
if ($height > $width) 
{   
$ratio = $maxheight / $height;  
$newheight = $maxheight;
$newwidth = $width * $ratio; 
$writex = round(($maxwidth - $newwidth) / 2);
$writey = 0;
{
else 
{
$ratio = $maxwidth / $width;   
$newwidth = $maxwidth;  
$newheight = $height * $ratio;   
$writex = 0;
$writey = round(($maxheight - $newheight) / 2);
}

$newimg = imagecreatetruecolor($maxwidth,$maxheight);

//Since you probably will want to set a color for the letter box do this
//Assign a color for the letterbox to the new image, 
//since this is the first call, for imagecolorallocate, it will set the background color
//in this case, black rgb(0,0,0)
imagecolorallocate($newimg,0,0,0);

//Loop Palette assignment stuff here

imagecopyresized($newimg, $img, $writex, $writey, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
```

That should work, haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 2):

[GD](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) or Imagick functions are what you need depending on your PHP configuration.
*Sorry I'm a newbie I can't post both links in the same message :(*

Comment: You don't need to use the shell to use imageMagick if you have it installed. There's a PHP class there: 
http://fr.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

Answer (score 1):

I have recently needed php resizing (thumbnail) solution and found [Zebra_Image library](http://stefangabos.ro/php-libraries/zebra-image/), which is a lightweight image manipulation library written in PHP. The code is really clean and it's also easy to use. I highly recommend using this library. The example code is just enough to get you started.

Be make sure that you have enough memory limit set in php.ini file to manipulate images which have relatively big resolution (e.g 2560x1600). I had an error with big images and there was no error to print. I debugged the problem down to `imagecreatefrom{gif,jpeg,png}` calls in `function _create_from_source` in lines **1262**, **1279**, and **1288**. The calls were silented with @ so I couldn't have a change to get the error. I removed @ lines and saw a PHP error that memory limit has been exceeded. The original memory limit was set to 32MB and I increased it to 64MB. Now I can manipulate 2560x1600 and I refuse to manipulate images which are bigger.

Below is the example code for controlling the image resolution.

```
    $image_properties = getimagesize($UPLOADED_FILE_PATH);                   
    $file_width = $image_properties[0];                                
    $file_height = $image_properties[1];                               

    if ($file_width > 2560 || $file_height > 1600) {    
        // handle your error whichever you like, I simply 'die' just to show               
        die('Cannot manipulate image bigger than 2560x1600');                                                                                                                                              
    }
```

(Note: I use Zebra Image version 2.2.2)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php):

```
convert susan.jpg -resize x200 susan_thumb.jpg
```

This runs with a shell command, so in PHP you'd use `shell_exec()` to run the above command.  I don't think you need any PHP extensions.

A few flags can be found in the ImageMagick documentation to control the resizing operation.  If I recall correctly, the `x200` before the number means "scale with the same aspect ratio to 200px".

I wrote an install guide for ImageMagick (and ghostscript): [How to install, test, convert, resize PDF using ImageMagick, Ghostscript, Windows Vista/7 x64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243361/pdf-convert-with-imagemagick-and-ghostscript-on-windows-vista-7-x64) based on my bumbling around, maybe it can help you.

The other option is the GD library (detailed in dqhendricks answer).  This is [faster](http://dreamfall.blogspot.com/2008/02/php-benchmarks-gd-vs-imagemagick.html)  and apparently better documented, used for basic operations.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need imagick. here is a link that will take you to a function that will resize any image using PHP GD to any arbitrary size. the function has options to use letterboxing or crop-to-fit methods to resize to the new aspect ratio. the function is also explained thoroughly. check it out.

http://www.spotlesswebdesign.com/blog.php?id=1

if this is what you are looking for, please select the check mark next to this answer. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Some says imagic faster, i use next

```
    
    function resizeImageProportional($imagePath, $destinationPath, $width = false, $height = false, $filterType = \Imagick::FILTER_POINT, $blur = 1, $bestFit = false, $cropZoom = false)
    {
        if (!$width && !$height) {
            trigger_error("WTF_IMAGE_RESIZE");
            return false;
        }
        //The blur factor where > 1 is blurry, < 1 is sharp.
        $imagick = new \Imagick(realpath($imagePath));
```

if (!$width || !$height) {
        $orig_width = $imagick->getImageWidth();
        $orig_height = $imagick->getImageHeight();
        $proportion = $orig_height/$orig_width;
        if (!$width) {
            $width = $height*$proportion;
        } elseif (!$height) {
            $height = $width*$proportion;
        }
    }

    if ($bestFit) {
        $imagick->resizeImage($width, $height, $filterType, $blur, $bestFit);
    } else {
        $imagick->resizeImage($width, $height, $filterType, $blur);
    }

    if ($cropZoom) {
        $cropWidth = $imagick->getImageWidth();
        $cropHeight = $imagick->getImageHeight();

        $newWidth = $cropWidth / 2;
        $newHeight = $cropHeight / 2;

        $imagick->cropimage(
            $newWidth,
            $newHeight,
            ($cropWidth - $newWidth) / 2,
            ($cropHeight - $newHeight) / 2
        );

        $imagick->scaleimage(
            $imagick->getImageWidth() * 4,
            $imagick->getImageHeight() * 4
        );
    }